# Java can't read a text file

Tags: java, parsing, text

I am trying to read a .txt file and search for a word, but the program just closes with `Process finished with exit code 0`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LogParser {
    static  Scanner file;
    static ArrayList text = new ArrayList();
    static String path = new String();
    static String check = new String();
    private static int a = 0;
    static  Scanner inpunt = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Input path to file");
        path = inpunt.nextLine();
        File texts = new File(path);

        try {
            file = new Scanner(new File(path)); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Can't open file");
        }

        try {
            while (file.hasNext()) {
                text.add(a, file.nextLine());
                check = text.get(a).toString();
                if (check.contains("cap"))
                    System.out.println("Allert!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + text.get(a));
                a = a + 1;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // System.out.println("Can't open file");
            if (file.toString().contains("cap"))
                System.out.println("cap" + "Path to file: " + path);
            System.out.println(text.size());
        }

    }

}
```

The text in the .txt file is:

```
let's try read this cap
```

If I try to open an xml file, everything is ok. My problem is only in txt files.

Comment: could you please try to explain yourself a bit better?

Comment: It's not clear where `path` is set. Please try and modify your code in a way that it's easy to reproduce the issue. What is the error/exception you're experiencing ? help us help you...

Comment: Path isn't set.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, your path variable isn't set. You're trying to create a new file and passing in a path that hasn't been instantiated.